# Who am I? When I have life, I remain silent even after getting much pain

Tags: riddle

> When I have life, I remain silent even after getting much pain
>
> But when I don't have life, I easily get hurt even after getting a single pain

**What am I?**

Answer (score 4):

You're obviously:

> A gamer playing Mario

When I have life, I remain silent even after getting much pain

> When the gamer has lives, he remains silent even when dying because he's got enough lives left

But when I don't have life, I easily get hurt even after getting a single pain

> When he's out of lives he gets hurt because he's ragequitting and hitting the NES game console after getting hit a single time

Nailed it

Answer (score 3):

I think this is quite a bit of a stretch, but...

> You are an uterus

When I have life, I remain silent even after getting much pain

> While carrying a fetus, the uterus stays put even when giving birth (getting much pain)

But when I don't have life, I easily get hurt even after getting a single pain

> Could be referring to menstrual cramps and periods

Answer (score 3):

Are you:

> A leaf

When I have life, I remain silent even after getting much pain

> Green leaves bend easily without breaking

But when I don't have life, I easily get hurt even after getting a single pain

> Dead leaves crack and crumble, making a lot of noise

Answer (score 1):

Are you:

> A motherboard?

When I have life, I remain silent even after getting much pain

> When you're turned on, you receive a lot of electricity, and it doesn't bother you.

But when I don't have life, I easily get hurt even after getting a single pain

> When you're turned off, a slight bit of electricity can destroy you

Also:

> Most would find electricity painful

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> Self-control

When it has life,

> one can go through a lot of pain.

But without it

> One can get hurt with a single pain

Answer (score 1):

What comes to mind is

> A starfish

When I have life, I remain silent even after getting much pain

> When alive it is silent and when its appendages get severed they grow back. So it can live through much pain.

But when I don't have life, I easily get hurt even after getting a single pain

> When it dies, it stiffens and becomes fragile. When the appendages get broken off they don't grow back. So it gets easily "hurt".